# How can I set the helm tiller namespace via an environment variable?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've previously installed tiller into a specific namespace.

I set an environment variable to set the 'tiller' namespace - but I can't remember what this environment variable was called - and can't seem to find it via a web search.

What is this key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TILLER_NAMESPACE
```

> Helm will look for Tiller in the kube-system namespace unless
>   --tiller-namespace or TILLER_NAMESPACE is set.

https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm#easy-in-cluster-installation

Answer (score 4):

By executing *helm -h* you can see the list of environment variables it uses:

```
Environment:
  $HELM_HOME          set an alternative location for Helm files. By default, these are stored in ~/.helm
  $HELM_HOST          set an alternative Tiller host. The format is host:port
  $HELM_NO_PLUGINS    disable plugins. Set HELM_NO_PLUGINS=1 to disable plugins.
  $TILLER_NAMESPACE   set an alternative Tiller namespace (default "kube-system")
  $KUBECONFIG         set an alternative Kubernetes configuration file (default "~/.kube/config")
  $HELM_TLS_CA_CERT   path to TLS CA certificate used to verify the Helm client and Tiller server certificates (default "$HELM_HOME/ca.pem")
  $HELM_TLS_CERT      path to TLS client certificate file for authenticating to Tiller (default "$HELM_HOME/cert.pem")
  $HELM_TLS_KEY       path to TLS client key file for authenticating to Tiller (default "$HELM_HOME/key.pem")
  $HELM_TLS_VERIFY    enable TLS connection between Helm and Tiller and verify Tiller server certificate (default "false")
  $HELM_TLS_ENABLE    enable TLS connection between Helm and Tiller (default "false")
```